# Setting dictionaries to properties

Tags: vba, excel, class

I'm not new to VBA but I am new to classes and I'm struggling at the moment with initialising some dictionaries.
Here's a cut down version of my class:

```
Option Explicit
'Variables required for object operations
Private pFilePath As String         'contains the file path of the TAB file.
...
Private pDATAFields As Object       'dictionary1
Private pMetadata As Object         'dictionary2

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pDATAFields = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set pMetadata = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub

...

Public Property Get DATAFields() As Object
    DATAFields = pDATAFields
End Property

Public Property Get Metadata() As Object
    Metadata = pMetadata
End Property

'Methods required
Public Sub initialise(sFilePath As String)

    'sTABText contains the text from file at sFilePath
    Dim sTabText As String
    sTabText = harvestTextFile(sFilePath)

    ...

    pTABVersion = pullPart("Version", strArr(1), 1)

    ...

    Set pDATAFields = generateFieldStructureDict(strArr, 6, 5 + pDATAFieldNumber)

    ...

    'Generate the metadata dictionary from the file
    Set pMetadata = generateMetadataDict(strArr, i + 1)
End Sub

Private Function generateFieldStructureDict(arg1 as string, arg2 as integer, arg3 as Integer) as Object
    Dim oObj as Object
    Set oObj = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    ... do stuff

    Set generateFieldStructureDict = oObj
End Function

... Similar function for generateMetadataDict
```

From my own observations this should work but for some reason it doesn't. The properties such as `pTABVersion` get set fine. It just appears to be `pDATAFields` and `pMetadata` which aren't getting set properly.

If I follow the function `generateFieldStructureDict` step by step I see that by the end of the function when I am doing:

```
set generateFieldStructureDict = oObj
```

this part works absolutely fine. The dictionary in `oObj` is passed onto `generateFieldStructureDict`. However when we then return to the initialise sub routine:

```
Set pDATAFields = generateFieldStructureDict(strArr, 6, 5 + pDATAFieldNumber)
```

`generateFieldStructureDict` appears to lose all the data I gave it. Ultimately `clsTab.filePath` and `clsTab.tabVersion` will return the `pFilePath` and `pTabVersion` (because they have been set). However `clsTab.DATAFields` and `clsTab.Metadata` will not return dictionaries like they are supposed to. This is because `pMetadata` and `pDATAFields` *are not* set for some reason.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with simpler code? Does it work with an early-bound `Collection` reference passed around like this? See [mcve] for some ideas =)

Comment: Your class propertie Get's are missing `Set` - E.g. `Set DATAFields = pDATAFields`

Comment: @Mat, Thanks I will try to trim it down more with a real example. It was lat last night when I wrote this post and I needed sleep!

Comment: @Tim - I knew it had to be a simple fix! Thanks a lot!